# HDF5 performance: row vs column selection

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I have a ~100 GB HDF5 file containing two large three-dimensional arrays of floats (training and validation data):

```
import h5py
dset = h5py.File("my_dataset.hdf5", "r")
```

Performance is very good for loading multiple rows into memory:

```
sub_dset_1 = dset["train"][1000:2000]
```

But indexing over the other axes is extremely slow:

```
sub_dset_2 = dset["train"][:, :, 0]
```

Questions:

1. What is the explanation for this behaviour?
2. Which data formats can be used to store large data on disk, while being able to load only parts of it to memory (along different axes)?

Comment: Most likely explanation is your chunk shape. Based on behavior you describe, I suspect the shape of `dset.train` is small for axis 0 and the max dimension for axis 2 and 3. So reading on axis=0 can effectively use chunking, but reading a slice on axis=2 or 3 requires accessing every single chunk. You can check the chuck shape with `dset['/train'].chunks`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not using chunking, so `dset["train"].chunks` returns `None`

Comment: `[1000:2000]` selects a contiguous block of data from the file.  `[:, :, 0]` selects values from the whole file.  I'd expect similar behavior with a numpy array, but smaller.  The array is all in memory, and `strides` pretty efficient. But the dataset is on a file, which can only be read 'linearly'.

Comment: Would MongoDB or SQLite be a more suitable solution?